# Collecting edges in a set from shortestPath iGraph Object

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path

I am trying to collect all the unique edges from object created from shortest_paths iGraph function.

```
> data<-as.matrix(data)
> data
  Q W E R T Y U I
Q 0 4 7 5 0 4 0 0
W 2 0 5 7 3 2 4 9
E 2 4 0 9 2 2 7 2
R 2 2 2 0 6 0 5 8
T 0 8 8 5 0 5 9 0
Y 4 7 2 6 0 0 5 7
U 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 9
I 2 0 6 7 0 2 0 0

network<-graph.adjacency(adjmatrix = data,weighted = TRUE, mode="directed" , diag = FALSE )

shortestPath<-shortest_paths(graph = network, from = 1, to = 1:8,mode = "out", output = "epath")

> shortestPaths$epath
[[1]]
+ 0/41 edges from b068eeb (vertex names):

[[2]]
+ 1/41 edge from b068eeb (vertex names):
[1] Q->W

[[3]]
+ 2/41 edges from b068eeb (vertex names):
[1] Q->Y Y->E

[[4]]
+ 1/41 edge from b068eeb (vertex names):
[1] Q->R

[[5]]
+ 2/41 edges from b068eeb (vertex names):
[1] Q->W W->T

[[6]]
+ 1/41 edge from b068eeb (vertex names):
[1] Q->Y

[[7]]
+ 2/41 edges from b068eeb (vertex names):
[1] Q->W W->U

[[8]]
+ 3/41 edges from b068eeb (vertex names):
[1] Q->Y Y->E E->I
```

I want to calculate the number of unique edges in the shortest path so that i can compute the density of the graph defined as -

Density = (Number of unique edges on shortest paths)/ (total number of edges)

This needs to be done for all pair shortest path in the graph.

How can i Count the number of unique edges that are on shortest path in an all pair setting.

Thanks

Comment: Did you meant `lengths(shortestPath$epath)/41`

Comment: No.
(1) The objective requires to calculate the number of distinct edges on all the shortest paths / 41
(2) length(shortestPath$epath) = integer(0) and also won't give the "number" of distinct edges

Comment: Please show your expected output ie. count of distinct edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unlist, find the unique edges and take the length of the resulting vector:

`length(unique(unlist(shortestPath$epath)))`